# Add HTTPs to Elastic Beanstalk with Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare

I am trying to add HTTPS connection to the server API I have in elastic beanstalk, using CloudFlare as DNS. Steps I have followed:

1. Go to AWS certificate manager and create a certificate for *.nameofmydomain.com
2. Verified the certificate
3. Created a listener in elastic beanstalk loader section, port 443 and the previously created certificate
4. Created a CNAME record in cloudflare that points api.nameofmydomain.com to the elastic beanstalk (xxxxx.yyyyy.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com)

When I open the https://xxxxx.yyyyy.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com I get the following error
[image]

And when I open the api.nameofmydomain.com I get this
[image]

Comment: Is cloudflare in DNS only mode or proxy mode for api.nameofmydomain.com?

Comment: @drussey proxy mode

Comment: That is odd, and means this SSL error is coming from Cloudflare. Is your SSL setup with cloudflare simple the free Universal SSL provided by cloudflare? Are you perhaps using an old browser and supporting only a newer cipher suite (TLS 1.3) on Cloudflare?

Comment: @drussey i'm using the last version of firefox and I didn't make any change in cloudflare regarding SSL so I am using default settings

Comment: I would switch over to DNS only to verify that your AWS beanstalk setup is correct, but I very much suspect it is correct because an SSL error between cloudflare and AWS would usually result in a cloudflare branded page that indicates an SSL issue.

Comment: @drussey if I switch to only DNS I get the same as the first screenshot (the warning portential security risk ahead)

Comment: @drussey I also have a landing page in nameofmydomain.com hosted in heroku, can the issue be related to that?

Comment: As long as DNS is set up correctly, it shouldn't matter about using Heroku. It should should work correctly with DNS only if the AWS set up is correct. Take a look at the subject and SANs that the AWS certificate has.  It should be nameofmydomain.com and *.nameofmydomain.com, or at least *.nameofmydomain.com.

Comment: @drussey thanks for you help troubleshooting, I finally found the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, [turns out that wildcard ACM certificates in AWS only work for one level](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-error-https/), and I was trying to create a domain in that was xxx.yyy.nameofmydomain.com changing it to just one level made it work

Comment: Ah, this makes sense for cloudflare as well. I thought your domain was one level - api.nameofmydomain.com - more than one subdomain level will also confuse Cloudflare's servers based on SNI and they won't be able to cover your site with their universal SSL cert.

Comment: It's not just wildcard ACM certificates in AWS, wildcard certificates only work at one level period, on any service on the Internet.

Comment: @MarkB oh okay, that's good to know, thanks!